# NullPointerException while filling an array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

This is a question about `NullPointerException`, what I'm tring to do is to set a symbol to every piece in my "pieces" array (the method `setSymbol` exists, and is a `char` value) 
I know this is null by default, but how do I set my array, if my "set method" doesn't work?

I'm being as brief as possible with my code

```
    Pieces[][] pzs = new Pieces[7][7];
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            pzs[i][j].setSymbol('X')
        }
    }
```

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Pieces[][] pzs = new Pieces[7][7]` makes a 7 by 7 array filled with nulls:

```
{{null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
 {null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
 {null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
 {null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
 {null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
 {null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
 {null,null,null,null,null,null,null}}
```

What you want to do is this:

```
Pieces[][] pzs = new Pieces[7][7];
//no need for int i, j
for(int i = 0; i < pzs.length; i++){     //pzs.length guarantees you won't get an 
    for(int j = 0; j < pzs[i].length; j++){ //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException even if pzs is something different
        pzs[i][j] = new Pieces();
        pzs[i][j].setSymbol('X')
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to Vulpix for suggesting using `pzs.length`

Comment: Just to add to @gangqinlaohu's answer: You may want to use `pzs.length` instead of `7` for the outer loop and `psz[0].length` for the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize each `Pieces`. Inside your inner `for`-loop add a line:

```
pzs[i][j] = new Pieces();
```

Also your array will run out of bounds, either declare more `Pieces` or cut 1 iteration of both `for`-loops.