# Null pointer exception using array of object

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
private class Record {
    float val;
    byte year;
}
....
Record[] record=new Record[100];
record[0].year=(byte)12;
```

I got exception on the last line.
Thanks!

Comment: There is no Record object in the array.  It's an array of *references* that can be set to point to Record objects, but you have to create the objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException while filling an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026133/nullpointerexception-while-filling-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise record[0] firstly.

```
Record[] record=new Record[100];
record[0] = new Record();
record[0].year=(byte)12;
```

This is different with C/C++. In Java, each element of an object array needs initialisation .

Answer (score 1):

By default arrays of objects are filled with `null`s so what you are doing in

```
record[0].year=(byte)12;
```

is in fact

```
null.year=(byte)12;
```

but `null` doesn't have its class so it doesn't have `year` field. To solve this problem you need to first fill your array with new objects of `Record` class like

```
Record[] record = new Record[100];
for (int i = 0; i < record.length; i++)
    record[i] = new Record();

//now you can safely use
record[0].year = (byte)12;
```

---

I just noticed that `Record` is `private` class which means that it is inner class. While you will be able to create its instances in non-static method via `new Record()` to create it in `static` method you will need first instance of its outer class. In that case your code can look like

```
OuterClass myOuterClassInstance = new OuterClass();
Record[] record = new Record[100];
for (int i = 0; i < record.length; i++)
    record[i] = myOuterClassInstance.new Record();

//now you can safely use
record[0].year = (byte)12;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `Record`s to array

```
Record[] record=new Record[100];

for (int i = 0; i < record.length; i++){
   record[i] = new Record(val, year);
}
```

This is considering you have a constructor `Record(float val, byte year);`